# optimizing mysql sub-query statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm making a community shares 'creepy pasta'.
My query takes 133ms now, but I wanna make the query faster.
just recommending a keyword is enough.

here are my tables.

> **Column Description:**
>
> **'cp_id'** means creepypasta's id.
>
> **'session_id'** is something like writer.
>
> **'creepy'** means how creepy the creepy pasta is. when 'creepy' is 0, it's not creepy story. but when that is 1, it's creepy.

```
 - creepypastas: id, alias, created_at, modified_at, title, content, session_id
 - creepypasta_comments: id, cp_id, created_at, content, session_id
 - creepy_points: id, cp_id, creepy, session_id
```

and here's my SQL query.

```
SELECT id, alias, created_at, modified_at, title, content, session_id, 
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(case creepy when 1 then 1 else 0 end), 0) FROM 
creepy_points c WHERE creepypastas.id = c.cp_id) AS creepy_count, 
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(case creepy when 0 then 1 else 0 end), 0) FROM 
creepy_points c WHERE creepypastas.id = c.cp_id) AS not_creepy_count, 
(SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM creepypasta_comments c WHERE creepypastas.id = 
c.cp_id) AS comment_count 
FROM creepypastas ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your query, you can add an index on `creepy_points(cp_id, creepy)`:

```
create index idx_creepypoints_cpid_creepy on creepy_points(cpid, creepy);
```